# Splitting by a semicolon not surrounded by quote signs

Tags: php, regex, csv, pcre, decoder

Well, hello community. I'm workin' on a CSV decoder in PHP (yeah, I know there's already one, but as a challenge for me, since I'm learning it in my free time). Now the problem: Well, the rows are split up by `PHP_EOL`.

In this line:

```
foreach(explode($sep, $str) as $line) {
```

where *sep* is the variable which splits up the rows and *str* the string I wanna decode.

But if I wanna split up the columns by a semicolon there might be a situation where a semicolon is content of one column. And as I researched this problem is solved by surrounding the whole column by quote signs like this:

**Input:**

```
"0;0";1;2;3;4
```

**Expected output:**

> 0;0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4

I already thought of lookahead/lookbehind. But as I didn't use it in past and maybe this could be a good practice for it I don't know how to include it in the regex. My decoding function returns a 2D-array (like a table...) and I thought of adding rows to the array like this (Yep, the regex is f***ed up...):

```
$res[] = preg_split("/(?<!\")". preg_quote($delim). "(?!\")/", $line);
```

And at last my full code:

```
function csv_decode($str, $delim = ";", $sep = PHP_EOL) {
    if($delim == "\"") $delim = ";";
    $res = [];

    foreach(explode($sep, $str) as $line) {
        $res[] = preg_split("/(?<!\")". preg_quote($delim). "(?!\")/", $line);
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function `str_getcsv` in this you can specify a custom delimiter(`;`) as well.

[**Try this code snippet**](https://eval.in/776832)

```
<?php

$string='"0;0";1;2;3;4';
print_r(str_getcsv($string,";"));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0;0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

Comment: was thinking about the same approach to avoid regex, also an array walk would be nice, to parse `0;0` and not have it as string but as an array.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix I haven't used regex, here i am using an inbuilt function of `PHP`.

Comment: it works well for the $string. but when quote change from double-quote to single-quote: $string="'0;0';1;2;3;4";  it fail.

Comment: @iBinary this is "the way to do it".  `str_getcsv()` is specifically built for this task and is especially handy.

Comment: @honglinzhang  Your requirements are slightly different to the posted question.  [See the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) 
 The default "enclosure" character is `"`.  If you need to change that to single quotes, add `'` to the 3rd parameter of the call like this: `str_getcsv($string, ";", "'")`

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit counter-intuitive, but the simplest way to split a string by regex is often to use `preg_match_all` in place of `preg_split`:

```
preg_match_all('~("[^"]*"|[^;"]*)(?:;|$)~A', $line, $m);
$res[] = $m[1];
```

The A modifier ensures the contiguity of the successive matches from the start of the string.

If you don't want the quotes to be included in the result, you can use the [branch reset feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) `(?|..(..)..|..(..)..)`:

```
preg_match_all('~(?|"([^"]*)"|([^;"]*))(?:;|$)~A', $line, $m);
```

---

Other workaround, but this time for `preg_split`: include the part you want to avoid before the delimiter and discard it from the whole match using the `\K` feature:

```
$res[] = preg_split('~(?:"[^"]*")?\K;~', $line);
```

Comment: That helped me a bit tbh. Maybe for an (let me say) advanced beginner (because I'm not on 0 skill-based but I obviously just know the basics like capturing groups, letter classes etc so advanced beginner and no intermediate) I wished more explanation because many of these features are totally new to me.

Comment: Let me try it:

The first regex: first capturing group is a quote sign followed by many none-quote sign-chars OR many none-semicolon-chars and non-quote sign-chars. Then a non-capturing which includes a semicolon or a dollar sign (which means the end of the string? I'm confused...)?

Comment: Second one: the mentioned branch reset group which idk... capturing group 1 includes many none-quote sign-chars and this group is surrounded by two quote signs. Group 1 can contain as well many none-semicolon-chars or none-quote sign-chars. The non-captured group includes semicolon or dollar sign.

Comment: After all what wasn't so hard as I expected I have to say that just the very end of the regex confuses me.

Comment: @iBinary: Yes there aren't difficult, the "dollar sign" is a special character: `$` is a zero-width assertion for the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Split is not a good choice for csv type lines.
You could use the old tried and true `\G` anchor with a find globally type func.

[Practical](https://regex101.com/r/0ZltQu/1)

Regex: `'~\G(?:(?:^|;)\s*)(?|"([^"]*)"|([^;]*?))(?:\s*(?:(?=;)|$))~'`

Info:

```
 \G                            # G anchor, start where last match left off
 (?:                           # leading BOL or ;
      (?: ^ | ; )
      \s*                           # optional whitespaces
 )
 (?|                           # branch reset
      " 
      ( [^"]* )                     # (1), double quoted string data
      "
   |                              # or
      ( [^;]*? )                    # (1), non-quoted field
 )
 (?:                           # trailing optional whitespaces
      \s* 
      (?:
           (?= ; )                       # lookahead for ;
        |  $                             # or EOL
      )
 )
```